# How to build a table in latex that one column can have three subcolumns

Tags: latex

I am trying to build a table in Latex that one column which in my case in "Factor Loading" has three subcolumns, and also text in the "Item" column to be wrapped if it too big.

[image]

Comment: In this case, you simply build a regular 5-column table and merge the three top right-hand side cells. The command for that is `\multicolumn{3}{c}{<text to display}`

Comment: Have a look at the `tabularray` package

Answer (score 1):

`\multicolumn{}{}{}` is the way to merge a number of cells but in your case, I would move *"Factor loading"* to a bottom part with annotations. The table seems to look more balanced without and the information is still there.

Here is the solution with a few improvements

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{tabularx}     % Mainly for X-type column. Also loads very useful `array` package
\usepackage{booktabs}     % For custom rules: \toprule, \bottomrule, \midrule, \cmidrule and \spacialrule
\usepackage{caption}      % For custom formatting of captions
\usepackage{ragged2e}     % Adds \RaggedRight and \Centering and improves text typesetting in narrow cells
\usepackage[nopar]{kantlipsum}   % Only for summy text - can be removed in final draft

\captionsetup[table]{position=top, skip=1pt}   % Adds a small gap between caption and a table

\newcommand\tn[1]{\rlap{\textsuperscript{#1}}}            % A custom macro to add an annotation mark 
\newcommand\thead[1]{\textbf{#1}}                         % Formats headings
\renewcommand{\tabularxcolumn}[1]{>{\RaggedRight}p{#1}}   % For X formatting. Here, it only adds \RaggedRight
\newcolumntype{F}[1]{>{\Centering}p{#1}}                  % A custom column-type. Adds centering to default left alignment of p{}


\begin{document}
\begin{table}[tbh]
  \renewcommand*{\arraystretch}{1.5}   % Stretch a table vertically adding small spacing between rows
  \centering
  \caption{The table}
  \label{tab:table}
  \begin{tabularx}{1.0\linewidth}{@{} p{2.2cm} | X | *3{@{}F{1.2cm}} @{}}
    \toprule
    \multicolumn{1}{@{}p{2.2cm}}{\thead{Construct}}   % \multicolumn can also cancel vertical bars around cells
    & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\thead{Items}}
    & \thead{KR}\tn{*}
    & \thead{SG}\tn{*}
    & \thead{US}\tn{*} \\
    \specialrule{\lightrulewidth}{3pt}{0pt}
    Collaborative & \kant[1][1] & 0.798 & 0.814 & 0.878 \\
                  & \kant[1][2] & 0.749 & 0.874 & 0.838 \\
                  & \kant[1][3] & 0.865 & 0.878 & 0.924 \\
                  & \kant[1][4] & 0.893 & 0.834 & 0.820 \\
                  & \kant[1][5] & 0.910 & 0.86  & 0.898 \\
                  & \kant[1][6] & 0.770 & 0.903 & 0.921 \\
    \specialrule{\heavyrulewidth}{0pt}{0pt}
    \multicolumn{5}{@{}l}{\tn{*}\hspace{0.25em} Factor loading}
  \end{tabularx}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

EDIT.
Also, as suggested, `tabularray` is another alternative. The package gives you very easy interface to actually paint tables. The downside is time of compilation, which is a few times longer than that of regular tables.

Answer (score 1):

Just for fun, here a variation with the `tabularray` package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularray}   
\usepackage{lipsum}  
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[tbh]
  \caption{The table}
  \label{tab:table}
  \begin{tblr}{|l|X|c|c|c|} 
    \hline
    Construct & Items & \SetCell[c=3]{} Factor loading &&\\
    \hline
    & & KR & SG & US \\
    \hline
    Collaborative & \lipsum[1][1] & 0.798 & 0.814 & 0.878 \\
                  & \lipsum[1][1] & 0.749 & 0.874 & 0.838 \\
                  & \lipsum[1][1] & 0.865 & 0.878 & 0.924 \\
                  & \lipsum[1][1] & 0.893 & 0.834 & 0.820 \\
                  & \lipsum[1][1] & 0.910 & 0.86  & 0.898 \\
                  & \lipsum[1][1] & 0.770 & 0.903 & 0.921 \\
   \hline
  \end{tblr}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: You couldn't resist, could you :D

Comment: @Celdor In fact I was just curious how much slower tabularray would be compared to the already slow tabularx. About 30% increased time :) ... given that I had to write the code for this test, I thought I could as well post it :P

Comment: I think it's even slower. I was so curious so I had to test it by myself. I created [test files](https://gist.github.com/celdorwow/4b6fce1de8b2c5bfb6b913660794f0b5) and compared timings. I measured time spent on multiple compilations to a have better estimation and here's are timings for `tabular`, tabularx`, and `tabularray`: 30.6s, 32.1s, 52.1s. It looks `tabularay` is over 60% slower than `tabularx`. I wonder how accurate it is :)